# ADO.NET Connected Approach

Tags: ado.net

In connected approach while working with Databases, how to add the date string in table from windows form from date time picker?

Answer (score 0):

Always use the property type, so don't use `string` for a `datetime`. You should use parameters to prevent sql-injection:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Table(DateCol)VALUES(@Date)", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```